# d3 bubble-chart react js: how to keep bubbles inside chart boundary?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to create force simulation bubble chart using d3 in react js. I have created chart with force simulation and drag & drop functionality. but the bubbles are getting out of svg element as shown in below image.

[bubble chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIO1k.png)

My BubbleChart component

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import * as d3 from "d3"
import * as _ from 'lodash'

export default class BubbleChart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            margin: { top: 0, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 0 },
            sizeDivisor: 0.8,
            color: null,
            nodePadding: 2.5,
            width: 0,
            height: 0
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { data } = this.props
        window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleResize)
        this.setState({
            color: d3.scaleOrdinal(["#597EF7", "#9254DE"])
        })
        this.simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        let tempData = data
        tempData.forEach((d) => {
            if (d.rad) {
                d.size = +d.rad * 120
                d.size < 1 ? (d.radius = 1) : (d.radius = d.size)
            } else {
                d.value = +d.value
                d.size = +d.value / this.state.sizeDivisor
                d.size < 3 ? (d.radius = 3) : (d.radius = d.size)
            }
        })
        this.graphdata = tempData.sort((a, b) => {
            return b.size - a.size
        })
        this.createBubblePlot(this.graphdata)
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        const { data } = this.props
        if (!_.isEqual(prevProps.data, this.props.data)) {
            let tempData = data
            tempData.forEach((d) => {
                if (d.rad) {
                    d.size = +d.rad * 120
                    d.size < 1 ? (d.radius = 1) : (d.radius = d.size)
                } else {
                    d.value = +d.value
                    d.size = +d.value / this.state.sizeDivisor
                    d.size < 3 ? (d.radius = 3) : (d.radius = d.size)
                }
            })
            this.graphdata = tempData.sort((a, b) => {
                return b.size - a.size
            })
            this.createBubblePlot(this.graphdata)
        }
    }
    createBubblePlot(data) {
        const node = this.node
        d3.select(node).selectAll("g").remove()
        const width =
            this.props.width - this.state.margin.left - this.state.margin.right
        const height =
            this.props.height - this.state.margin.top - this.state.margin.bottom
        this.simulation
            .force(
                "forceX",
                d3
                    .forceX()
                    .strength(0.1)
                    .x(width * 0.5)
            )
            .force(
                "forceY",
                d3
                    .forceY()
                    .strength(0.1)
                    .y(height * 0.5)
            )
            .force(
                "center",
                d3
                    .forceCenter()
                    .x(width * 0.5)
                    .y(height * 0.5)
            )
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-15))

        let nodeg = d3
            .select(node)
            .attr(
                "width",
                width + this.state.margin.left + this.state.margin.right
            )
            .attr(
                "height",
                height + this.state.margin.top + this.state.margin.bottom
            )
            .append("g")
            .attr(
                "transform",
                "translate(" +
                    this.state.margin.left +
                    "," +
                    this.state.margin.top +
                    ")"
            )

        let nodes = null
        let nodestext1 = null
        let nodeinnercircle = null

        this.simulation
            .nodes(data)
            .force(
                "collide",
                d3
                    .forceCollide()
                    .strength(0.5)
                    .radius((d) => {
                        return (
                            (width / height / 2) * d.radius +
                            this.state.nodePadding
                        )
                    })
                    .iterations(1)
            )
            .on("tick", function (d) {
                nodes
                    .attr("cx", (d) => {
                        return d.x
                    })
                    .attr("cy", (d) => {
                        return d.y
                    })

                nodestext1
                    .attr("x", (d) => {
                        return d.x
                    })
                    .attr("y", (d) => {
                        return d.y
                    })

                nodeinnercircle
                    .attr("cx", (d) => {
                        return d.x
                    })
                    .attr("cy", (d) => {
                        return d.y
                    })
            })

        let nodedata = nodeg.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter()

        nodes = nodedata
            .append("circle")
            .attr("r", (d) => {
                return (width / height / 2) * d.radius
            })
            .attr("fill", (d) => {
                if (d.color) {
                    return d.color
                } else {
                    if (d.type === "a") {
                        return "#597EF7"
                    } else {
                        return "#9254DE"
                    }
                }
            })
            .attr("fill-opacity", (d) => {
                if (d.rad) {
                    let opacity = d.rad.toFixed(2)
                    if (opacity >= 1) {
                        return opacity
                    } else if (opacity < 1 && opacity > 0.4) {
                        return 0.8
                    } else if (opacity < 0.4 && opacity > 0.04) {
                        return 0.6
                    } else {
                        return 0.5
                    }
                } else {
                    return 1
                }
            })
            .attr("cx", (d) => {
                return d.x
            })
            .attr("cy", (d) => {
                return d.y
            })
            .on("mouseover", this.mouseOver)
            .on("mouseout", this.mouseOut)
            .call(
                d3
                    .drag()
                    .on("start", this.dragstarted)
                    .on("drag", this.dragged)
                    .on("end", this.dragended)
            )

        nodeinnercircle = nodedata
            .append("circle")
            .attr("cx", (d) => {
                return d.x
            })
            .attr("cy", (d) => {
                return d.y
            })
            .attr("r", (d) => {
                if (d.label === "" || d.label === " ") {
                    return 0
                } else {
                    return 11
                }
            })
            .attr("visibility", (d) => {
                if (d.label === "" || d.label === " " || !d.label) {
                    return "hidden"
                } else {
                    return "visible"
                }
            })
            .attr("fill", "#000000")
            .attr("fill-opacity", "0.24")

        let nodetxt = nodeg.selectAll("text").data(data).enter()

        nodestext1 = nodetxt
            .append("text")
            .attr("x", (d) => {
                return d.x
            })
            .attr("y", (d) => {
                return d.y
            })
            .attr("dy", ".3em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.label
            })
            .attr("font-family", "SF-Pro-Display-Semibold")
            .attr("font-size", "12px")
            .attr("font-weight", 600)
            .attr("line-height", "20px")
            .attr("fill", "white")

        this.simulation.alphaTarget(0.03).restart()
    }

    dragstarted = (e, d) => {
        if (!e.active) this.simulation.alphaTarget(0.03).restart()
        d.fx = e.x
        d.fy = e.y
    }

    dragged = (e, d) => {
        d.fx = e.x
        d.fy = e.y
    }

    dragended = (e, d) => {
        if (!e.active) this.simulation.alphaTarget(0.03)
        d.fx = null
        d.fy = null
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                style={{
                    height: this.props.height,
                    width: this.props.width,
                    border: "1px solid #000000"
                }}
            >
                <svg
                    style={{
                        height: this.props.height,
                        width: this.props.width
                    }}
                    ref={(node) => (this.node = node)}
                ></svg>
            </div>
        )
    }

    handleResize = () => {
        this.setState({ width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight })
        this.createBubblePlot(this.graphdata)
        //     this.forceUpdate();
    }

    mouseOver = (e, data) => {
        if (data) {
            if (data.label !== "" && data.label !== " ") {
                if (this.props.onMouseOver) {
                    this.props.onMouseOver(e, data)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    mouseOut = (e, data) => {
        // console.log("onMouseOut")
        if (data) {
            if (data.label !== "" && data.label !== " ") {
                if (this.props.onMouseOut) {
                    this.props.onMouseOut(e, data)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to keep the bubbles from getting out of the svg for given height and width? (or bubbles should collide with chart boundary)

codesandbox link for my example

https://codesandbox.io/s/d3-force-simulation-bubble-chart-react-vxb5j

Answer (score 1):

Try adding all your bubbles inside a g which leaves the margins